# Script to extract a list of all the images on a web page  (web scraping code)

Tags: shell, scripting

I would like a script that can extract a list of all the images (e.g. `*.jpg`) on a web page, i.e. urls ending with `.jpg`

With this script, I would pipe the output to file using `>` and then use the piped output as input into `wget`.

Is this possible using the shell script.

(Edit: I am using the `bash` shell)

Comment: no its more possible with javascript!!!

Comment: how? means wget or grep can not help

Comment: Depends what you mean by shell scripting.  Which shell?  And more importantly, once you get that list of all *.jpg's what are you going to want to do with it?  I've posted a Ruby example of how you can both finding the *.jpg and then download them.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Bash shell...
if i get list of images on that site then i copy that list to text file and then i can download all images by just wget -i inputfile

Comment: @user1625013 - then why not use `wget` to scrape the entire html file and then `grep` to pull out the *.jpg, `>` pipe that to `inputfile` and then run `wget -i inputfile` as you've suggested?  Or you can use the Ruby code I've posted :D -- it does exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`lynx`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx)?

```
lynx -image_links -dump www.google.com |
    grep '\. https\?://.*\.\(gif\|jpg\|png\)$'
```

To clean-up the output a bit you can use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
lynx -image_links -dump www.google.com |
    grep '\. https\?://.*\.\(gif\|jpg\|png\)$' |
    cut -d . -f 2- |
    cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Comment: +1  Neat - never knew lynx had additional functionality as a utility besides for simply browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Since, not all shells provide web connectivity out of the box (certainly the Windows shell doesn't), a solution in a dynamic scripting language (something like Ruby or Python) would work across platforms.

Here's some Ruby code that, when pointed to a webpage, searches it for *.jpg's, lists them all, and then downloads them.  (BTW, it can be used for PDFs, PNGs, whatever you wish, with simple modification.)

```
#  web page scraper that downloads jpgs (or easily PDFs, txt files, csvs, etc.)   AKE  (1/2009)

require 'net/http'

# take instructions from the command line

my_domain_name = ARGV[0]  # JUST the domain name
my_path = ARGV[1]         # the path separated on either end by /
my_filename = ARGV[2]     # the html filename

puts "Scraping #{my_domain_name + my_path + my_filename}"

response = "empty"  

Net::HTTP.start( my_domain_name ) do |http|
     response = http.get( my_path + my_filename ).body
 end

# writing scraped html into text file, for reference / debugging
open("scraped.txt", "wb") {|s|
  s.write(response)
}

 # parse the response  to make list of jpg files
 files = response.scan(/\w+.jpg/)

 # download each jpg
files.each do |file|
   image_filename = file
   puts "Writing #{image_filename}..."
   Net::HTTP.start(my_domain_name) do |http|
   jpg = http.get(file)
   open(image_filename, "wb") {|p|
     p.write(jpg.body)
   }
   end
   puts "Done!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to download all the images too:

```
for i in `lynx -image_links -dump http://www.google.com | grep 'jpg\|gif' \
| grep http | awk '{print $2}'`; do wget $i; done
```